# Cannot mount an ISO image file with PowerShell

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell

```
PS F:\ISOs\System>  [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version



Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
10     0      14393  0

PS F:\ISOs\System> dir


Directory: F:\ISOs\System


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
...
-a----        11/1/2013     13:32      134971392 Win7PE2.iso
...

PS F:\ISOs\System> Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath .\Win7PE2.iso -Verbose
Mount-DiskImage : The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath .\Win7PE2.iso -Verbose
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (MSFT_DiskImage:ROOT/Microsoft/.../MSFT_DiskImage) [Mount-DiskImage], CimException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070002,Mount-DiskImage
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the full path to the .ISO file.

e.g.:

`Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath 'F:\ISOs\System\Win7PE2.iso' -Verbose`

From Microsoft's [Mount-DiskImage TechNet entry](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848706(v=wps.630).aspx), and from `Get-Help Mount-DiskImage` within PowerShell:

> This cmdlet requires the full path of the VHD or ISO file.

Comment: Oh my, I don't know why I did not notice this. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks! What an incredibly strange restriction and stupid error message, though.

Answer (score 2):

In case you'd like to use it in a script or you are too lazy to type the full path (as I am), you can go with:

```
Mount-DiskImage ((Get-Item -Path ".\" -Verbose).FullName+"\ISONAME.iso")
```

Comment: I don't see the point of this script: why would you use `Get-Item` and then, later on, specify the ISO's name by yourself? Something along `$a = @(Get-ChildItem -Include *.iso) | Select-Item -ExpandProperties FullName; Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath $a[0] -Verbose` would seem much more elaborate to me.

Answer (score 0):

My option:

```
$mountResult = Mount-DiskImage (Get-Item $iso).VersionInfo.FileName -PassThru -ErrorAction Stop
```

where $iso contains relative or absolute path